# Sequences of Natural Numbers without Arithmetic Subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, natural-numbers

Let's call a sequence $k^+$-free if it is contains no arithmetic *subsequence* of length $k$.  Define the $\bf{density}$ of a sequence of natural numbers $s_n$ as $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{s_n}$$

Do all $k^+$-free sequences have density $0$?

All geometric series $s_n = i^n$ for $i \ge 2$ are $3$-sequences, for example.  It seems that these are the "densest" possible $3$-sequences.  This observation is consistent with the above.

Perhaps it is possible to construct a proof using strong induction.

EDIT: I'm reviving this question because I actually would like to see the solution for the case when we require that there be no arithmetic subsequence of length $k$.

Comment: I doubt very much that geometric series are the densest $3^+$-free sequences! And yes, I realise that my "doubt very much" is no more convincing than your "It seems". I hope to get back to you on this.

Comment: Can you find one denser than the following (altered) geometric sequence?

$1,1,2,2,4,4,8,8,16,\dots$

Comment: There is a string of $2$s of length $3$.

Comment: when u consider an AP, do u take only the consecutive terms of the sequence or you can skip a few terms ?

Comment: @Alex No.  It is not $k^+$ for large enough $k$ because it has arbitrarily long sequences of constants.

magguu, You can only take consecutive terms in the sequence.

Comment: Somehing less sparse than geometric sequence is the sequence of fourth powers $0^4$, $1^4$, and so on. But undoubtedly one can get far less sparse than that with no AP of length $3$.

Comment: A good sequence that avoids to be $3^+$ is $s_n=\sum c_i 3^i$ if $n=\sum c_i 2^i$ ("write binary, read ternary")

Comment: @AndrewSalmon, fibonacci numbers?

Comment: @user58512 Yes, that is $3^+$ but $1,1,2,2,4,4,\dots$ is denser since the Fibonacci sequence $F \sim \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}^n$ which is sparser.

Comment: what if you just do, 1,1+2,1+2+1,1+2+1+2,...?

Comment: @user58512 Wow good point.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon, this problem is really interesting for sets rather than sequences, it's called Roth's theorem for k=3 or Szemermedis theorem for all k.